# extract key of object from a dynamic typed object

Tags: typescript

I have this interface:

```
interface test {
   [key: string]: string
}
```

and this object:

```
const obj: test ={
   name: 'mda',
   telephone: '1234'
}
```

now when i want to use this obj in variable the intellisense not working for this  object. in other word i can choose a key that it does not exist in object.

```
const myName = obj.ndfnasdfn
```

and compiler not show error for this key.
this is playground area: [playground](http://interface%20test%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20[key:%20string]:%20string%20%7D%20const%20obj:%20test%20=%7B%20%20%20%20%20name:%20'mda',%20%20%20%20%20telephone:%20'1234'%20%7D%20const%20myName%20=%20obj.msdamfsamdfm)

update to a nested object :
for this nested object what is solution:
i use @Titian Cernicova-Dragomir solutin for the nested object in below but the compiler does not show error.

```
interface test {
[key: string]: string
 }

 function createTest<T extends test>(o: T) {
     return o;
 }
 interface state {
     test1: test,
     test2:test
 }
 const state: state = {
    test1:createTest({
        t1:'m',
        t2:'e'
  }),
  test2: createTest({
    t3:'sss'
     })
  }
 const {test1, test2} = state
 const t1 = test1.sdfsafsdf //no error
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20test%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20createTest%3CT%20extends%20test%3E(o%3A%20T)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20o%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Ainterface%20state%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20test1%3A%20test%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20test2%3Atest%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aconst%20state%3A%20state%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20test1%3AcreateTest(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20t1%3A'm'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20t2%3A'e'%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20test2%3A%20createTest(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20t3%3A'sss'%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aconst%20%7Btest1%2C%20test2%7D%20%3D%20state%0D%0Aconst%20t1%20%3D%20test1.sdfsafsdf)

update 2: 
if we don't use the createTest function so we get the purpose as we don't specify type to state like this [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20test%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20state%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20test1%3A%20test%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20test2%3Atest%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aconst%20state%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20test1%3A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20t1%3A'm'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20t2%3A'e'%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20test2%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20t3%3A'sss'%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aconst%20%7Btest1%2C%20test2%7D%20%3D%20state%0D%0Aconst%20t1%20%3D%20test1.t12)

my answer was that i use type for state and get a compiler error for the keys that they don't exist in test1

Answer (score 2):

If you specify the type of the variable explicitly, as you have, that will be the final type of the variable, the compiler will to infer anything extra for the variable.

If you want to let the compiler infer the type just remove the annotation

```
const obj ={
   name: 'mda',
   telephone: '1234'
}
```

If you want to constrain the variable to have only string values, you will need to use a function to constrain the type but let the compiler still infer the type:

```
interface test {
    [key: string]: string
}

function createTest<T extends test>(o: T) {
    return o;
}

const obj = createTest({
    name: 'mda',
    telephone: '1234'
    // age: 10 // error not a string
});
obj.name //ok
obj.sss //error
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20test%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20createTest%3CT%20extends%20test%3E(o%3A%20T)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20o%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20obj%20%3D%20createTest(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20'mda'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20telephone%3A%20'1234'%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2Fage%3A%2010%20%2F%2F%20error%0D%0A%7D)%3B%0D%0Aobj.name%20%2F%2Fok%0D%0Aobj.sss%20%2F%2Ferror)

For your nested sample, you will need a function to create `state` not just `test`. The same principle applies, if you explicitly specify the type of `test1` and `test2` that will be the final type regardless of the type `createTest` will return.

```
interface test {
    [key: string]: string
}

interface state {
    test1: test,
    test2:test
}
function createTest<T extends state>(o: T) {
    return o;
}
const state = createTest({
    test1: {
        t1: 'm',
        t2: 'e'
    },
    test2: {
        t3: 'sss'
    }
});
const {test1, test2} = state
const t1 = test1.sdfsafsdf //error
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20test%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20state%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20test1%3A%20test%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20test2%3Atest%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Afunction%20createTest%3CT%20extends%20state%3E(o%3A%20T)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20o%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aconst%20state%20%3D%20createTest(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20test1%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20t1%3A%20'm'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20t2%3A%20'e'%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20test2%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20t3%3A%20'sss'%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)%3B%0D%0Aconst%20%7Btest1%2C%20test2%7D%20%3D%20state%0D%0Aconst%20t1%20%3D%20test1.sdfsafsdf%20%2F%2Ferror)

Comment: compiler does not show error for obj.sss  palyground

Comment: @MDA because of the extra `age` I had to prove only strings would be accepted. commented it in the answer.

Comment: @IanMacDonald MDA was right I screwed up the original answer, fixed it after he commented it works now. :)

Comment: @MDA unsure what the constraint you are seeking is .. object can have any nested object with only string properties Or it must only have specific defined ones ?

Comment: i use your solution for nested object but compiler does not show error.

Comment: @MDA again the same principle applies, if you explicitly specify the type of `test1` and `test2` that will be the final type regardless of the type `createTest` will return. You can create another function to infer the types for `test1` . Updated the answer

Comment: i updated the answer and use your function to create test1 object

Comment: @MDA I added a playground link. Are you still having issues it was not clear from your last comment ..

Comment: we can get this purpose without the createTest function.

Comment: @MDA You can get it if you fix the keys to a specific test and not have the index signature in `test`. If you have the index signature you can access with any key. Unfortunately typescript can't infer the type of a variable and check a constraint we need a function for that ..